# how to export spring boot actuator metrics to a log file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to dump actuator metrics to log file.

Tried using metricsEndpointMetricReader but could not get any results.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire the all the PublicMetrics , and extract the result to a map and log it.

```
public class MetricExtractor {

    @Autowired
    List<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics;

    public void extract() {
       Map<String,Object>map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
       for(PublicMetrics publicMetrics : publicMetrics) {
           for(Metric<?> metric : publicMetrics.metrics()) {
              map.put(metric.getName(), metric.getValue());
           }
       }
       log.info("metrics :: {} ", map );
   }

}
```